# Akka streams with gilt aws kinesis exception: Stream is terminated. SourceQueue is detached

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm using gilt aws kinesis stream consumer library [there](https://github.com/gilt/gfc-aws-kinesis/blob/master/akka.md) to connect to a single shard kinesis stream.

Specifically:

```
    ...
    val streamConfig = KinesisStreamConsumerConfig[String](
      streamName = queueName
      , applicationName = kinesisConsumerApp
      , regionName = Some(awsRegion)
      , checkPointInterval = 5.minutes
      , retryConfig = RetryConfig(initialDelay = 1.second, retryDelay = 1.second, maxRetries = 3)
      , initialPositionInStream = InitialPositionInStream.LATEST
    )

    implicit val mat = ActorMaterializer()

    val flow = Source.queue[String](0, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
      .to(Sink.foreach {
        msgBody => {
          log.info(s"Flow got message: $msgBody")
          try {
            val workAsJson = parse(msgBody)
            frontEnd ! workAsJson
          } catch {
            case th: Throwable => log.error(s"Exception thrown trying to parse message from Kinesis stream, e.cause: ${th.getCause}, e.message: ${th.getMessage}")
          }
        }
      })
      .run()

    val consumer = new KinesisStreamConsumer[String](
      streamConfig,
      KinesisStreamHandler(
        KinesisStreamSource.pumpKinesisStreamTo(flow, 10.second)
      )
    )

    val ec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    ec.submit(new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = consumer.run()
    })
```

The application runs fine for about 24 hours, I verify occasionally by pushing records using `aws kinesis put-record` command line and watch them getting consumed by my application, but then suddenly the application start receiving exceptions each time a new record is pushed to the stream.

Here is the console logging when that happens:

```
INFO: Sleeping ...                                                                                                                                                                     [863/1962]
 DEBUG[RecordProcessor-0000] KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl - Processing 1 records from shard shardId-000000000000
 WARN [RecordProcessor-0000] KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl - Kinesis shard: shardId-000000000000 :: Stream is terminated. SourceQueue is detached
 WARN [RecordProcessor-0000] KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl - Kinesis shard: shardId-000000000000 :: Stream is terminated. SourceQueue is detached
 WARN [RecordProcessor-0000] KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl - Kinesis shard: shardId-000000000000 :: Stream is terminated. SourceQueue is detached
 ERROR[RecordProcessor-0000] KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl - SKIPPING 1 records from shard shardId-000000000000 :: Kinesis shard: shardId-000000000000 :: Stream is termi
nated. SourceQueue is detached
com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLRecordProcessorFactory$KCLProcessorException: Kinesis shard: shardId-000000000000 :: Stream is terminated. SourceQueue is detached
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl$$anon$1.$anonfun$doRetry$2(KCLRecordProcessorFactory.scala:156)
        at com.gilt.gfc.util.Retry$.retryWithExponentialDelay(Retry.scala:67)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl$$anon$1.doRetry(KCLRecordProcessorFactory.scala:151)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl$$anon$1.processRecords(KCLRecordProcessorFactory.scala:120)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.processRecords(V1ToV2RecordProcessorAdapter.java:42)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.ProcessTask.call(ProcessTask.java:176)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:49)
        at com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary.lib.worker.MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.call(MetricsCollectingTaskDecorator.java:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Stream is terminated. SourceQueue is detached
        at akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$1.$anonfun$postStop$1(Sources.scala:57)
        at akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$1.$anonfun$postStop$1$adapted(Sources.scala:56)
        at akka.stream.stage.CallbackWrapper.$anonfun$invoke$1(GraphStage.scala:1373)
        at akka.stream.stage.CallbackWrapper.locked(GraphStage.scala:1379)
        at akka.stream.stage.CallbackWrapper.invoke(GraphStage.scala:1370)
        at akka.stream.stage.CallbackWrapper.invoke$(GraphStage.scala:1369)
        at akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$1.invoke(Sources.scala:47)
        at akka.stream.impl.QueueSource$$anon$2.offer(Sources.scala:180)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.akka.KinesisStreamSource$.$anonfun$pumpKinesisStreamTo$1(KinesisStreamSource.scala:20)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.akka.KinesisStreamSource$.$anonfun$pumpKinesisStreamTo$1$adapted(KinesisStreamSource.scala:20)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.akka.KinesisStreamHandler$$anon$1.onRecord(KinesisStreamHandler.scala:29)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.akka.KinesisStreamConsumer.$anonfun$run$1(KinesisStreamConsumer.scala:40)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.akka.KinesisStreamConsumer.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(KinesisStreamConsumer.scala:40)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLWorkerRunner.$anonfun$runSingleRecordProcessor$2(KCLWorkerRunner.scala:159)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLWorkerRunner.$anonfun$runSingleRecordProcessor$2$adapted(KCLWorkerRunner.scala:159)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:52)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLWorkerRunner.$anonfun$runSingleRecordProcessor$1(KCLWorkerRunner.scala:159)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLWorkerRunner.$anonfun$runSingleRecordProcessor$1$adapted(KCLWorkerRunner.scala:159)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLWorkerRunner.$anonfun$runBatchProcessor$1(KCLWorkerRunner.scala:121)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLWorkerRunner.$anonfun$runBatchProcessor$1$adapted(KCLWorkerRunner.scala:116)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl$$anon$1.$anonfun$processRecords$2(KCLRecordProcessorFactory.scala:120)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
        at com.gilt.gfc.aws.kinesis.client.KCLRecordProcessorFactory$IRecordProcessorFactoryImpl$$anon$1.$anonfun$doRetry$2(KCLRecordProcessorFactory.scala:153)
        ... 11 common frames omitted
```

Wondering if [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44210274/664690) answer might be related. If so, I'd appreciate simpler explanation/how-to-fix that suits a newbie like myself

Notes:

- This is still in testing/staging phase so there is no real load to
     the stream except for the occasional manual pushes I'm making
- The 24h duration in which the application runs fine is not
     accurately tested but was an observation.
- I'm running the test for a third time (started at 8:42 UTC) but with 
     the difference of increasing Source.queue buffer size to 100.
- If 24h turns out to be accurate, could that be related to Kinesis 
     default 24h retention period of stream records?

**Update:**

Application still working fine after 24+ hours of operation.

**Update2:**

So the application has been running fine for the past 48+ hours, again the only difference is increasing the stream's `Source.queue` size to 100.

- Could that be the proper fix to the issue?
- Will I face similar issue with increased load once we go to production?
- Is 100 enough/too much/too few?
- Can someone please explain how this change fixed/suppressed/metigated the error?

Comment: Same issue as you, I'm wondering what I'm supposed to do...